# How can I programatically determine which methods have been declared as "helper" methods by a controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller, actionviewhelper

I'm writing a plugin that adds a method to controllers and declares it as a helper method. If it were done statically (rather than through the plugin), it would look something like this:

```
# in RAILS_ROOT/app/controllers/stuffed_animals_controller.rb
class StuffedAnimalsController < ActionController::Base

  private

  def bear
    'Teddy Bear'
  end

  helper_method :bear

end

# in RAILS_ROOT/app/views/stuffed_animals/index.html.erb:
<%= bear -%>
```

It works just fine. I want to test that `:some_helper_method` is *actually* a helper method, though.  I tried this:

```
def test_declared_bear_as_helper_method
  assert StuffedAnimalsController.helper_methods.include?(:bear)
end
```

Unfortunately, `ActionController::Base` does not have a `:helper_methods` class method. Anyone know where I can get the list of things a class exposes via `:helper_method`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
def test_declared_bear_as_helper_method
  helper = Object.new
  helper.extend StuffedAnimalsController.master_helper_module
  assert helper.respond_to?(:bear)
end
```